# HID Smart Card Reader Linux Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, pcsc

I am using raspberry Pi  . I have installed libusb then PSCD lite after that i have installed drivers for HID Smart Card Reader 5021 CL i am getting this error. Any idea i think that error is due to the reason of some permissions as i am using the user pi and owners of these directory is root .  I am new to linux  and the directory and file is there on the path shown below

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/pcsc-tools $ sudo pcscd -f
00000000 dyn_unix.c:60:DYN_LoadLibrary() /usr/local/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifdokccid_linux_i686-v4.1.8.bundle/Contents/Linux/ifdokccid.so: /usr/local/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifdokccid_linux_i686-v4.1.8.bundle/Contents/Linux/ifdokccid.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
00001913 readerfactory.c:1019:RFInitializeReader() RFLoadReader failed: 0x80100014
00000172 readerfactory.c:335:RFAddReader() OMNIKEY CardMan (076B:5340) 5021 CL (OKCM0030812141011235703916649119) init failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drivers are for PC (architecture `i686`) you need drivers for ARM (probably `armhf` architecture).

AFAIK drivers for ARM are not available from HID.

Comment: Youre quite right any how i figured it out using CCID library  available it supported my card and i read it using it .... as manufacture doesnt provide driver for it ... I can read the ATR and UID but still struggling to read serial number of card from UID any idea regarding this ?

Comment: @AbdulBasit Could you share how you got CCID alone to handle the reader? All I need is UID and I'm having a similar issue with an Omnikey 6321 on a Pi. Any insight you have would be appreciated.

Comment: @AbdulBasit I m also trying to interact with the 5321 CLI on a raspberryPI but did not manage to have it working with pcscd or libccid. Could you please explain how you manage to interact with the reader ? Any chance you have any note/code somewhere ?